Mini split Circuit
I’ve recently installed the Mr Cool DIY 12k minisplit which calls for a 20 amp service. I wired everything up but the breaker pops immediately when activated. I’ve confirmed my wiring but have a couple of questions. I installed a fused disconnect which upon further research have learned is redundant since the circuit is on a breaker. I also mistakenly put a 30amp fuse in the disconnect. I plan to correct that with a 20 amp fuse. Would the fused disconnect cause the breaker to pop? Also, I noticed that some of the fuses in my panel have terminals for both black and white wires while the 20 amp breaker that I placed only has a single terminal for the black. Whats the difference? Are some considered single pole and others double pole? Do I need a double pole 20 amp breaker? Thanks

Read the instructions again.
Does it call for 120v(a single breaker) or 240v(a double breaker).
The 30 amp disconnect is just for working on the unit/to turn off nearby.  Does not matter if 20 amp or 60 amp.It is just a switch.
Breaker tripping right away usually means a dead short.  The hot is touching ground and/or neutral(if used). Recheck, with the breaker off, all connections.  Look for bare ground wire close to hot/black wire/screw.  It is a common problem for us non experts.

The instructions for MR Cool 12K system call for a 115volt power supply to the outdoor unit. The installation manual is here. Connection is on page 33.  It uses a hot and neutral.  If you are wiring to a double breaker it is wired wrong.
The recommended wire is #12 prefered is #10 Breaker is 20A
A wiring diagram is also printed on the inside of the cover for the electrical connections.
